# How to send instagram DM everyday at specific time using Python(Instabot)?

Tags: python, instagram

I am using the Instabot library to send the message on Instagram however I wanted to make a python program that will send a direct message on Instagram every day at a specific time. The below code demonstrates how to send a message however If I were to send it every day at a specific time how would I do it?

```
from instabot import Bot 
from datetime import datetime,timedelta 

HOURS = 18 
def send_message():
    bot = Bot()  
    today = datetime.now()
    hours_added = timedelta(hours = HOURS)
    future_date_and_time = today + hours_added

    melbourne_time = future_date_and_time.strftime("%H:%M %p")

    if(melbourne_time== "09:00 AM"):
        bot.login(username="myusername", password="pass")
        bot.send_message("My message",["Personame"])
```

Any Help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a python time module like:

```
import time

if("1:30" in time.ctime()):
    """Enter your message"""
```

You can also use a while loop to check the time

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response, Yeah my program does check the time however, I would have to run my python Program every day to send messages. All I want is once I am done with writing the code, it should send the message every day by itself. Basically, I want to automate the process and make my life easy.

Comment: In my opinion the solution is:
1- keep your pc on (impossible)
2- put ur code in a server.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called Schedule, that will help you to achieve this :

```
pip install schedule
```

Here's how you can modify the code.

```
from instabot import Bot 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule
import time

HOURS = 18 

def send_message():
    bot = Bot()  
    bot.login(username="myusername", password="pass")
    bot.send_message("My message", ["Personame"])

def schedule_job():
    # Schedule the job to run every day at the specified time
    schedule.every().day.at("Your Time").do(send_message)

    # Run the scheduler continuously
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedule_job()
```

Replace ("Your Time") with actual time. And username with the real one same goes for the password. Feel free to ask if you've any doubt.